# Merging lines changes geometry

Tags: qgis-3, geometry-conversion

I'm sorry for the newbie question, but I'm picking up QGIS after a few months' absence, and I feel like everything is confusing again. I have imported some kml tracks, and put them into a GeoPackage layer of line topology. A few of the tracks have breaks in them (when the GPS didn't have a signal) and I want to merge those tracks into one.

I turned on snapping, drew a new straight line to connect the two I want to merge, and then selected the three lines and selected the "Merge Selected Features" menu item. This succeeds perfectly, but then I get this very annoying error:

> Could not commit changes to layer Temp Lines
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added - geometry type is not compatible with the current layer.

With some browsing here, I think that the lines were merged to a polyline, but that information doesn't help me. How do I merge lines and have the resulting shape be a line?

@bable asked me some questions, which I think I am supposed to answer here inline (sorry if this is breach of posting etiquette):

**When does the error occur?** When I try to save the layer.

**Is your layer single- or multipart?** It is of type "geometrytype=LineString" which I assume is single-part.

**Did you try to convert [the layer type]?** No. It seemed like it would be a lot of time trying to figure out things. I look in the manual and it talks about "Polyline" features, and I remember that this is an option when I create a layer. But I can't figure out from the manual whether a "multipart line" layer is the same as a "polyline" layer, and I thought it would just be easier to keep it as a line layer if possible.

**Did you try to copy the features and paste it as a new layer?** Yes. When I had a layer for which the error message said two features could not be saved, I then created a new "line" layer and copied each feature over, one by one, saving after every paste, to identify which features were of the wrong type. I have not figured out how to tell the type of a feature, so I could by inspection tell which was the wrong type for the layer that it is in.

Line #1 comes in from the left and terminates at "A", line #2 spans "A" to "B", and line #3 extends from "B" beyond the bottom of the image. I "Merge Features" on these selected items.

[image: Merging lines]

Comment: Can you add more details? When does the error occur: when you try to save? Is your layer single- or multipart? Did you try to convert it? Like Multipart to singleparts or the other way round. Did you try to copy the features and paste it as a new layer?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but was not "successful". Is there a possibility you could share sample data?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using QGIS 3.16.0 on MacOS. The project is here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhgwzg312rdrkge/Line%20Merge%20Example.zip?dl=0). I turn on editing for the layer, select all 3 lines, choose "Merge Selected Features" and then try to save the layer. Thank you, babel, for your persistence in helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, I had the same problem with the line you provided. To solve the problem, right click the layer, select `export / Save Features As…` (1), in the dialog window set geometry type to line and - attention - `Force multi-type` (2), click OK (3).

You get a new layer. Now you can easily select all the features (Ctrl-A on Win - or use the selection tool), toggle edit mode (4) and Merge Selected Features (5). Toggle edit mode again, now you should be able to save the merged line. Worked for me.

[image]

You can avoid this problem if you draw your connecting line properly. In the example, I deleted the small, connecting line, saved, and than added a new line again, connecting the dangles of the two lines, snapping to the end point of one and the start point of the next line. Like this, I was able to merge all three lines without exporting it to a multiline layer. So I guess that this connecting line was not properly drawn.

After some testing, I can prove this assumption: I extracted the vertices of the line layer you provided: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Extract vertices`. For visualization, I styled the different lines in different colors: yellow and blue for the original lines, green for the connecting line you draw by snapping. I than set a label on the extracted vertices with the expression `$x` and `$y` to get the x and y coordinates of the vertices. As you can see from the resulting screenshot, the vertices of the green line has not exactely the same coordinate values as the end point of the yellow and the start point of the blue line.

Since your project has the project CRS EPSG:32610, I suppose that you created your line in this CRS while your line layer is in EPSG:4326, so probably it is a projection issue (rounding of coordinate values). If you stick to EPSG:4326 and only in the last step, when finalizing your map, change to EPSG:32610  - or when you first re-project your GPS-tracks to EPSG:32610 and only than create the connecting line, you can probably avoid this problem.

[image]

I changed the labels to show the coordinates in EPSG:3261 - I did not reproject, just exchanged to labels from `$x` and `$y` to

```
x ( transform ( make_point ( $x, $y ), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32610' ) )
y ( transform ( make_point ( $x, $y ), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32610' ) )
```

You can see that the coordinates are (with one minor exception) the same:

[image]

Comment: OMG, that is a thorough answer. It boggles my mind, but makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, consider accepting this answer: click the check mark next to the question on the left side: i.stack.imgur.com/fpe2V.png See [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem saving LineString with merged line segments.  A solution that worked was to set the snapping to only the active layer, then set the snapping type to both vertices and line segments.  For some reason this worked.  I'm not sure why.